# Can't understand javascript code

Tags: javascript

I've found some code and would like to understand how it works, can somebody explain to me what this part

```
 if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
            alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
            elements.eq(rand).show();
            ++i;
        }
```

of the code does?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".champ").hide();

    var elements = $(".champ");
    var elementCount = elements.size();
    var elementsToShow = 4;
    var alreadyChoosen = ",";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < elementsToShow) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
        if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
            alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
            elements.eq(rand).show();
            ++i;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
div.champ {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    color: red;
}
p {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.champ:hover p {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/251-Celebi-icon.png">
    <p>Celebi, the 251</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/151-Mew-icon.png">
    <p>Mew, the 151</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/003-Venusaur-icon.png">
    <p>Venasaur, the 3</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/133-Eevee-icon.png">
    <p>Eevee, the unique</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/006-Charizard-icon.png">
    <p>Charizard, the 6</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/025-Pikachu-icon.png">
    <p>Pikachu, the 25</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/009-Blastoise-icon.png">
    <p>Blastoise, the 9</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/065-Alakazam-icon.png">
    <p>Alakazam, the 65</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/026-Raichu-icon.png">
    <p>raichu, the 26</p>
</div>
<div class="champ">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hektakun/pokemon/72/249-Lugia-icon.png">
    <p>ho-oh, the 249</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, others yes, but I couldn't understand what were these line doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
 //As soon as DOM is ready it is jQuery Syntax
$(".champ").hide(); // Hide all elements with class="champ"

var elements = $(".champ"); // Get All elements with class="champ"
var elementCount = elements.size(); // Store count of elements, you can also use .length instead of .size()
var elementsToShow = 4; // No. of elements to be shown
var alreadyChoosen = ","; // Just a String
var i = 0; //loop variable
while (i < elementsToShow) { // Loop through all 4 elements
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount); // Generate a random number between 0-4
    if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) { // check if that element was already chosen? '.indexOf()' returns -1 if no match found
        alreadyChoosen += rand + ","; // if not append it to that string
        elements.eq(rand).show(); // From collection of elements show only that particular element. '.eq()' is jQuery function
        ++i; // Increment loop variable
    }
}
});
```

See Comments for details. Hope it helps.

For More Details:

[.size()](https://api.jquery.com/size/)

[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

[.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

[Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

So Here is what that code does in a nutshell, As soon as document is loaded it'll hide all elements with `class="champ"` and then will show all those elements in random manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript index_of() function to check if a substring exists in a string. If the substring supplied (in this case, `",<some random number>,"`) does not exist, the function returns -1.

This code is checking to see if the element already exists. and if not (if it return something < 0), it shows it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to author intentions it should display `elementsToShow` number of  pokemons, chosen randomply from element list. As result you will receive `alreadyChoosen` string, which will hold list of ids joined by commas, like so:

```
1,2,3,6,1
```

There is only one problem with this approatch. Random cannot be predicted. If you have 5 pokemon in your inventory, and number of pokemon to display is 4 or even 5, then you may be stuck in a long loop, before it ends.

Code:

This will choose random number from 0..elementCount

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
```

And this one will check if this number has been already checked

```
if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
```

But this aproatch has another bug:
If we randomly choose 2, and inside this list will be a number containing 2 character, like 22, 12. It will pass, because you are comparing strings, not numbers.

In my opinion, this should look something like this:

```
var elementsToChoose = [0,1,2,3,4,...,elementCount]
var index= Math.floor(Math.random() * elementsToChoose.length);
var newElement = elementsToChoose [index];
// remove your new element from array
elementsToChoose .splice(index, 1)
```

You first alocate an array with index of every element, than randomly pop (get and remove) random element, untill you got enought of them